# Arabic months in Date function PHP

Tags: php, datetime, arabic

i have variable contains date and i want to print this date in  Arabic. date(months in Arabic language) how i can do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @Dale do you need to know what he has tried in order to post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$standard = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$eastern_arabic_symbols = array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩");
$current_date = date('d').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('Y');
$arabic_date = str_replace($standard , $eastern_arabic_symbols , $current_date);
```

you can try `str_replace` function

Comment: i have tried this with English and Arabic months and it worked.i have forgot to say that i use this in Drupal views php field, thank you for your reply .

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
$months = array(
    "Jan" => "يناير",
    "Feb" => "فبراير",
    "Mar" => "مارس",
    "Apr" => "أبريل",
    "May" => "مايو",
    "Jun" => "يونيو",
    "Jul" => "يوليو",
    "Aug" => "أغسطس",
    "Sep" => "سبتمبر",
    "Oct" => "أكتوبر",
    "Nov" => "نوفمبر",
    "Dec" => "ديسمبر"
);

$your_date = "2012-12-25"; // for example

$en_month = date("M", strtotime($your_date));

$ar_month = $months[$en_month];

echo $en_month . " = " . $ar_month;
```

This will output: `Dec = ديسمبر` and it depends on `$your_date`.

Comment: thank you for your reply  i tried LoverOfEvening answer and itworks for me it is close to what you say .

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "ar_AE");
```

Then print your date.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use `IntlDateFormatter` like that :

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('ar_SA',IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL);
$date = new DateTime();//now;
echo $formater->formate($date);//will print you something in arabic with the order that is used localy instead of english order.
```

Comment: This is supposed to be the best way as you got Arabic months for different calendars. eg, 'ar_SA', 'ar_JO'
Use the following to set custom format:
$dateFormatterAr->setPattern('yyy MMMM dd');

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't check for the month in English and then print the Arabic equivalent?